# In Javascript how are pixels in availHeight different to style pixels

Tags: javascript, css, pixel

I want to put four buttons on a page and spread their size to fill the height of the page so I am dividing `window.screen.availHeight` by 4. When I set the button style height to the result of that division (`.style.height = buttonHgt + 'px';`) it only fills half the page.

On my Galaxy S4 Android the `window.screen.availHeight` gives me 640. Before I resize the height of my four buttons they are 250px in height (according to their style.height setting) but don't fill the page. Pixels in `window.screen.availHeight`don't appear to be the same as pixels in style settings.

Is there a way I can get the height of my screen in CSS pixels?!

Comment: A pixel is a pixel, something else must be going on ?

Comment: @cpburnz - no it's not, but two javascript methods generally use the same "pixels".

Comment: availHeight talks about actual monitor/vid card pixels, whereas style works with logical pixels. on desktop they are typically 1:1, but on mobile, the virtual viewport is usually larger than the physical, which is how you pan around. http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Comment: Thx dandavis - the article you refer to is interesting and confirms my understanding that CSS and device pixels are not the same on all platfroms. I'm still none the wiser as to how to get the height of my device screen in CSS pixels and not device pixels